# joomla with ajax

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I allocate a module in a item of menu, my module call this function

```
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_arquero', $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

my default.php is this

```
<script>
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        //función a ejecutar cuando esté listo el dom

        $('descripcion').addEvent('click', function(evento){
            var nuevoRequest = new Request({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6',
                onRequest: function() { alert(' Ajax!'); },
                onSuccess: function(texto, xmlrespuesta){ $('arPrincipal').set('html',texto);}
            }).send();

        });

    });
</script>


<div id="contenedor">
    <div id="arqMenu">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="descripcion" id="descripcion">Descripción</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="arquitectura">Arquitectura</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="integracion_ti">Integración con TI</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="instalaciones">Instalaciones tipo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="especificaciones">Especificaciones</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="arqPrincipal">aqui va todo el txto</div>
</div>
```

I have four static page, when I click in description I want to show a page description in this div= arqPrincipal

I am missing something?

Comment: You did not explain what problem you are experiencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has typo error.div id is different than you mentioned in Ajax call.
Try this-

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TcgE2/)

```
<script>
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        //función a ejecutar cuando esté listo el dom

        $('descripcion').addEvent('click', function(evento){
            var nuevoRequest = new Request({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6',
                onRequest: function() { alert(' Ajax!'); },
                onSuccess: function(texto, xmlrespuesta){ $('arqPrincipal').set('html',texto);}
            }).send();

        });

    });
</script>
```

Let me know if it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.post('index.php',{
                        'option':'component_name',
                        'controller':'controller_name',
                        'task':'task_name',
                        'format':'raw',                   
                        'data': data
                },function(result){                     
                      //edit the result here

                    return;
       });
```

Try this and let me know. Don't forget to change the variables as you needed too.